# openldap search acl

Tags: openldap, access-control-list

I'm trying to write an access control for OpenLDAP to allow a user to search with a certain base dn, but only get results back from certain sub dn's.
I've played with lots of different rules but cant get it to work. I'm not sure its even possible.

For example:
I have the user with the dn `uid=testuser,ou=people,dc=example,dc=com`. I want this user to be able to search with a base of `dc=example,dc=com` and get back entries in `ou=people,dc=example,dc=com`. There are lots of other sub OUs under `dc=example,dc=com`, but only entries in `ou=people` should be returned (for bonus, I'd only like certain attributes to be returned as well).

Can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured this out. There are lots of different parts to this to make it work.

First the 2 ACL rules:

```
Access to dn.base="dc=example,dc=com" by \
  dn.base="uid=testuser,ou=people,dc=example,dc=com" \
  search

Access to dn.one="ou=people,dc=example,dc=com" \
  attrs=entry,uid,cn,sn,gecos,mail,uidNumber,gidNumber by \
  dn.base="uid=testuser,ou=people,dc=example,dc=com" \
  read
```

- Order of the rules does not matter because we are using `dn.base` on the 'access to' for the first rule. If it were 'dn.children', order would matter.
- The first rule grants `uid=testuser` search access to `dc=example,dc=com`, but absolutely nothing more. Without the second rule all that would come back was whether the search matched anything or not, not what it did match.
- The second rule grants `uid=testuser` read access to `ou=people` and the children one level deep (`dn.one`). Search ability is included in the read permission.
- The `entry` attr is important on the second rule as performing a search requires access to this attr to be able to match the entry.
- Once the entry is matched, the search will come back with all the other attributes that were permitted.